# How do I detect when a Quick Look panel is dismissed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, quicklook

I've written a Quick Look plugin that attempts to play music like this:

```
OSStatus GeneratePreviewForURL(void *thisInterface, QLPreviewRequestRef preview, CFURLRef url, CFStringRef contentTypeUTI, CFDictionaryRef options)
{
    NSURL *fileURL = (__bridge NSURL*)url;

    AudioPlayer *player = // load player with fileURL

    // Create a semaphore
    sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    // Start playback and signal the semaphore once finished
    [player play:^{
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];

    // Wait here until the player completion block signals the semaphore to stop waiting
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    NSLog(@"%@", @"done!");

    return kQLReturnNoError;
}
```

For various reasons, it's not practical for me to transcode these audio files into a format that macOS knows, or else I could just hand the OS an MP3 file and get the system's plugin to play it for me. So instead I'm using a dirty hack with semaphores to halt execution to keep my player object around, or else it'd abruptly stop immediately after starting playback.

The problem with that is that the file will just continue playing after the Quick Look panel stops previewing it due to the quicklookd process still running.

Is there a way to stop playback the way the system plugins do when they're dismissed?

Comment: Can your plugin implement the `CancelPreviewGeneration` callback, or poll `QLPreviewRequestIsCancelled`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use following delegate methods:

**According to Apple Documentation:**

> func previewControllerWillDismiss(QLPreviewController)
>   Called before the preview controller is closed.
>   func previewControllerDidDismiss(QLPreviewController)
>   Called after the preview controller is closed.

Comment: That's not useful, as I'm writing a Quick Look plugin.